# Show document title instead of file name in PDF-Reader

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, metadata

Today I opened a PDF document with Acrobat Reader DC and noticed that it showed the document title (not the filename) in the tab and title bar (which I like). Apparently, it is a property of the PDF file whether the reader (at least Acrobat Reader) should show the document title or filename; Acrobat Reader DC *Pro* can be used to change which one to show (see [this link from the adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2201918)).

When using pdfLaTeX with `hyperref` to produce a PDF with a document title (like in the example beneath), it shows the filename in Acrobat Reader. Is there a way to change this so it shows the document title?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftitle=Title,pdfauthor=Me]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
The filename is shown.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftitle=Title,pdfauthor=Me,pdfdisplaydoctitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
The title is shown.
\end{document}
```